# Issue with some characters on my contact form

Tags: php, forms, utf-8, contact-form

I am experiencing a strange issue with my contact form. It has been working just fine for a while but lately I have been receiving some broken messages when people use non ordinary characters such as ä, ö or å. So, to sum it up, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not and this issue has only recently started to happen. I would leave you with the php code for the form processing but it has more then 200 lines. [I can leave you instead the link of where did I get it from.](http://www.freegive.co.uk/freecontactforms.php) (the second form from the top with file upload)

Please let me know if you need me to paste here the code anyway.

Hopefully you can tell me what the problem might be. Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

After a little more investigation I came to conclusion that the characters ä, ö and å are not in the list of utf-8 that I use in m y contact form. Strange because like I said, I have the form on-line for some months now and only recently I started to have problems. Plus, I use the same character encoding (utb-8) in other contact forms in the same website and I don't get the same issue there.

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?PHP
/*
    Contact Form from Freegive

    This program is free software published under the
    terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will
be useful - WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

@copyright freegive.co.uk 2010
*/
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}
/*
FGContactForm is a general purpose contact form class
It supports Captcha, HTML Emails, sending emails
conditionally, File atachments and more.
*/
class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $age;
    var $experience;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;
    var $mailer;

    function FGContactForm()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }

    function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
    {
        $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
        session_start();
    }

    function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
    {
        $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
    }

    function SetFromAddress($from)
    {
        $this->from_address = $from;
    }
    function SetFormRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->form_random_key = $key;
    }
    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
    }
    function GetFormIDInputName()
    {
        $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());

        $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
        return 'id'.$rand;
    }


    function GetFormIDInputValue()
    {
        return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
    }

    function SetConditionalField($field)
    {
        $this->conditional_field = $field;
    }
    function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
    {
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
    }

    function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
    {

        $this->fileupload_fields[] =
            array("name"=>$file_field_name,
            "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
            "maxsize"=>$max_size);
    }

    function ProcessForm()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Validate())
        {
            $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
            return false;
        }
        $this->CollectData();

        $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

        return $ret;
    }

    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->error_message;
    }
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    function GetName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function GetEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    function GetMessage()
    {
        return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    }

/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */

    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Bio skickade till Vidösternsimmet från $this->name";

        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

        $this->AttachFiles();

        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Fel! Skickande av meddelandet misslyckades. Vänligen försök igen!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function CollectConditionalReceipients()
    {
        if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
          !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
          !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
        {
            foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
            {
                if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
                !empty($rec))
                {
                    $this->AddRecipient($rec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Internal variables, that you donot want to appear in the email
    Add those variables in this array.
    */
    function IsInternalVariable($varname)
    {
        $arr_interanl_vars = array('scaptcha',
                            'submitted',
                            $this->GetSpamTrapInputName(),
                            $this->GetFormIDInputName()
                            );
        if(in_array($varname,$arr_interanl_vars))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function FormSubmissionToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                $ret_str .= "<div class='label'><strong>$key: </strong> $value </div>\n\n";
            }
        }
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upload_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upload_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }        

            $filename = basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $ret_str .= "<div class='label'><strong>Avatar skickade:</strong> '$field_name' : $filename </div>\n";
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }

    function ExtraInfoToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP adress från sändare:</div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";

        return $ret_str;
    }

    function GetMailStyle()
    {
        $retstr = "\n<style>".
        "body,.label,.value { font-family:Arial,Verdana; } ".
        ".label {font-weight:bold; margin-top:5px; font-size:1em; color:#333;} ".
        ".value {margin-bottom:15px;font-size:0.8em;padding-left:5px;} ".
        "</style>\n";

        return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLHeaderPart()
    {
         $retstr = '<!DOCTYPE html">'."\n".
                   '<html><head><title></title>'.
                   '<meta charset="utf-8" />';
         $retstr .= $this->GetMailStyle();
         $retstr .= '</head><body>';
         return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLFooterPart()
    {
        $retstr ='</body></html>';
        return $retstr ;
    }
    function ComposeFormtoEmail()
    {
        $header = $this->GetHTMLHeaderPart();
        $formsubmission = $this->FormSubmissionToMail();
        $extra_info = $this->ExtraInfoToMail();
        $footer = $this->GetHTMLFooterPart();

        $message = $header."<h1>Ny Bio inför Vidösternsimmet:</h1><p>$formsubmission</p><hr/>$extra_info".$footer;

        return $message;
    }

    function AttachFiles()
    {
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $filename =basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES[$field_name]["tmp_name"],$filename);
        }
    }

    function GetFromAddress()
    {
        if(!empty($this->from_address))
        {
            return $this->from_address;
        }

        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $from ="bio_svara_inte@$host";
        return $from;
    }

    function Validate()
    {
        $ret = true;
        //security validations
        if(empty($_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()]) ||
          $_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()] != $this->GetFormIDInputValue() )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Automated submission prevention: case 1 failed<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
        if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //experience validations
        if(empty($_POST['experience']))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen skriv en erfarenhet nivå!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['experience'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen försök att beskriva din erfarenhet nivå med ett eller två ord!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //age validations
        if(empty($_POST['age']))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen skriv en ålder!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['age'])>3)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Det är osannolikt att du är mer än 99 år gammal och kan faktiskt simma 21+ Km! Vänligen skriv din verkliga ålder<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //name validations
        if(empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen skriv ett namn!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Ditt namn är för lång. Vänligen använd en förkortning!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //email validations
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen ange en e-post adress<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['email'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Email address is too big!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(!$this->validate_email($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Vänligen ange en giltig e-post adrerss<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //message validaions
        if(strlen($_POST['message'])>3048)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Meddelandet är för stort. Försök att ladda upp en mindre avatar!<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret = false;
        }

        //captcha validaions
        if(isset($this->captcha_handler))
        {
            if(!$this->captcha_handler->Validate())
            {
                $this->add_error($this->captcha_handler->GetError());
                $ret = false;
            }
        }
        //file upload validations
        if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
        {
         if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
         {
            $ret = false;
         }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
    {
        $ret=true;
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
        $extn = $info['extension'];
        $extn = strtolower($extn);

        $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
        if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Tillåtna filer är: $valid_filetypes<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            $ret=false;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
    {
        $size_of_uploaded_file =
                $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/2524;//size in KBs
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
        {
            $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Din avatar är alldelles för stort. Vänligen välj ett avatar som är mindre än $max_size KB<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
    {
        if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function ValidateFileUploads()
    {
        $ret=true;
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

            $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];

            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
            {
                $this->add_error('<div class="alert-box alert">Fel under avatars uppladdningen process; Error code:<a href="" class="close">&times;</a></div>'.$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
             !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
            $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
            {
                if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
                {
                    $ret=false;
                }
            }

        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function StripSlashes($str)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    /*
    Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
    data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
    if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
    */
    function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /*Collects clean data from the $_POST array and keeps in internal variables.*/
    function CollectData()
    {
        $this->name = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $this->email = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);

        /*newline is OK in the message.*/
        $this->message = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message']);
    }

    function add_error($error)
    {
        array_push($this->errors,$error);
    }
    function validate_email($email)
    {
        return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
    }

    function GetKey()
    {
        return $this->form_random_key.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You should post the code here: if that code isn't available anymore on that site, this question and its answer may well become useless.

Comment: 583 lines. Should I really post it here?

Comment: @deceze thanks! Because I did not find any bug I asked here. Because so much I know that sometimes the problem is not on the code. I know that you are not a debug service, I am sorry that you got so disturbed by my question or if my request harmed you in some way, but if you don't want to help you don't need to be rude. Once again thanks!

Comment: @deceze Besides, if the issue would be the code, the problem would be happening every time someone uses the form with the above mentioned characters which it doesn't happen. Like I said, only recently I got this problem and only sometimes, not every time.

Comment: The usual way of doing is to remove functionalities one by one until the problem disappear. If it doesn't, or if you don't understand why a certain functionality triggers the issue, you post a question containing a minimal program exposing the symptoms. As it stands, the code is indeed too long for us to handle. I think that's what other people have been trying to tell you. Sorry that I did not explain that sooner.

Comment: Just glancing at the code, I see that there's some input validation going on: this is perhaps a place to check first for text broken transformations.

Comment: @didierc I really appreciate your help, now I know where to start! That is very valuable to me! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long and patient debugging, I couldn't find any error in the code. Therefore, I decided to take contact with the hosting company where the website is hosted and ask for some guidance. They also looked at the code and said that it seemed to be all OK. After some chat we came to the conclusion that the most likely cause for this issue is the use of very old browsers/email clients from both users and admin - which I know is the case.

This may be not the right answer, but it is the answer that so far fits better into the situation because as I previously said, this is a problem that does not happen all the time but only sometimes. The admin **sometimes** uses his very old job computer (with a really old OS and browser) to read the messages that come in via form in that website. Therefore I will accept this as a correct answer!

If anyone has a better explanation, I am all ears...